# angular-highcharts not able to plot box plot

Tags: angular, highcharts, boxplot

In my application I am using angular-highcharts with Angular 5. I tried plotting box plot and I get following error:

```
ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:237)
at eval (highcharts.js:261)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at a.each (highcharts.js:27)
at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:261)
at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:237)
at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:236)
at new a.Chart (highcharts.js:235)
at a.chart (highcharts.js:235)
```

I tried using same sample data provided on https://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot .Many other charts seems to work. Following configuration I have:

@angular/cdk: 5.2.2
@angular/cli: 1.7.3

"angular-highcharts": "^5.2.11",
"highcharts": "^6.0.7",

Here is the source code of my component file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';


@Component({
selector: 'app-box-plot',
templateUrl: './box-plot.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./box-plot.component.css']
})
export class BoxPlotComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()
option: any;

chart: Chart;

constructor() {


this.option = {

  chart: {
    type: 'boxplot'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    title: {
      text: 'Experiment No.'
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Observations'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 932,
      color: 'red',
      width: 1,
      label: {
        text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
        align: 'center',
        style: {
          color: 'gray'
        }
      }
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Observations',
    data: [
      [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
      [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
      [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
      [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
      [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
    ],
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Outlier',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
      [0, 644],
      [4, 718],
      [4, 951],
      [4, 969]
    ],
    marker: {
      fillColor: 'white',
      lineWidth: 1
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
    }
  }]

};

this.chart = new Chart(this.option);
}

ngOnInit() {

}

}
```

Comment: Did you look at: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17. Are you sure you have imported both highcharts and highcharts-more?

Comment: @ewolden I tried that now Followed the instructions provided at https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts#using-highcharts-modules. Now I get different error:                                                                                                  TypeError: chartModule is not a function
    at eval (angular-highcharts.es5.js:287)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ChartService.initModules (angular-highcharts.es5.js:286)
    at new ChartModule (angular-highcharts.es5.js:308)
    at _createClass (core.js:10891)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10865)

Comment: I don't have experience using angular. That said, I suggest you create a working example (e.g. at stackblitz.com) and then update your question to include that. Then I am sure someone will come along and point you in the right direction.

Comment: @ewolden I tried on  stackblitz.com. And it seems to work. The only difference which I see now is , I am using Highchart in shared module and on stackblitz I am importing highchart in appModule. Can it make any difference ?

Comment: @ewolden Now it works. Only surprising thing is if I use syntax mentioned on git hub : import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src'; then it does not work. If I change same line like import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src'; It works. No idea to me how does it makes difference ? Thanks for your help ewolden.